# is there anyway we can get control of SAML assertion lifetime which is defined in NotOnOrAfter attribute?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, pac4j

I need to use SAML assertion lifetime for deciding the expiry of the API key, is there any way we can get the SAML session/assertion validity from the identity provider, I know using **notonorafter** attribute that value can be retrieved but can we update that value in IDP in some way?

Comment: what is exact use case? do you want to extend the existing token validity? AFAIK, you cannot modify the validity of the assertion through client.

Comment: I want to consume the token validity in my application, don't want to extend but want to get the expiry datetime

Comment: whats the problem with NotOnOrAfter? - it will give you server date-time, convert it to milliseconds and use it?

Comment: NotOrOrAfter and NotBefore has a difference of only 10 mins, which doesn't provide what i want, i wanted the session lifetime in identity provider which is usually 24 hours or so, depends on idp to idp.
SAML protocol don't provide the way to get that session validity through the authentication response in SAML assertion.